# Icons displaying in selected state in more tabbar controller IOS8

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios8

I am using a tab bar controller in my app, and I have more tab bar view controllers. In iOS 8 icons that are assigned to tabs in more tab bar are always in selected(Blue) state, which worked fine in iOS7?

```
image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];
UITabBarItem *tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:title image:image tag:tag];
```

[image]

Comment: have you added this icons from Storyboard or programmatically?

Comment: can you add your code please?

Comment: @panchaz Adding the code in the comments is not the best idea. You should normally edit your question with this information. Imagine if there is a chain of twenty comments? I've edited it now for you :)

Comment: @Kheldar thank you. i will keep that in mind next time

Answer (score 0):

you can try with following code:

```
UITabBar *tabBar = tabBarController.tabBar;
UITabBarItem *tabBarItem1 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0];

[tabBarItem1 setImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"tab1"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]];
[tabBarItem1 setSelectedImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"tab1Selected"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]];
[tabBarItem1 setTitle:title];
```

and you can do the same things with other tabs